# Using Scheduled Task Agent with Periodic Task local notification at a particular time in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Using Scheduled Task Agent with Periodic Task in Windows Phone 8 how do i show the local notification at a particular time. For example at (9AM and 5 PM) every day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't as it's impossible to schedule it for any specific time frame. From the MSDN documentation:

> Periodic agents typically run every 30 minutes. To optimize battery life, periodic agents may be run in alignment with other background processes and therefore the execution time may drift by up to 10 minutes.

Other options available if you need that level of precision are
1) [Programmatically set a reminder for the specific time that you want](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202965%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).
2) Push notifications from an external service to subscribed devices at your specified interval. Bear in mind that Push notifications delivery is slightly unreliable on windows phone.